# Integrating a $C^1$, piece-wise smooth, function in $[0,1]^n$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, monte-carlo

I am calculating a $\int_U f(x) dx$ where $f$ is $C^1$ and piece-wise smooth, while $U$ is the six-dimensional unit cube. $f$ fails to be $C^2$ across some smooth surfaces.

I have been applying a Monte Carlo method. Essentially, to get an additional digit of accuracy, I need to apply 100 times more computation.

Do I have a better option?

Comment: Is $f$ given explicitly as a formula?

Comment: @user251257  yes, however f is defined as a piecewise defined function

Comment: Is that function complicated? You might want to post it also

Comment: @user251257  [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTrianglePicking.html) is the basic setup. If we let $A=$ area, then $f=A$ is $C^0$, while $f=A^2$ is smooth, etc. Dividing the region will make $f$ to to  be smooth in each section but the  program becomes complicated.